# First Login Link Not Working

Tags: php, html, css, facebook

I have a login button working fine on web.

The second part of my code is for a collapse menu.

When I add this same exact login link to the collapse menu for mobile users, it does not authenticate the first login link for the non mobile navbar. I have to resize my  browser to ge the collapse menu to appear. Then use that login button.

So this code is the problem

```
 echo '<dd><a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'user_tagged_places, user_friends, email, publish_actions, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos, user_about_me, user_checkins, friends_checkins, user_location, friends_location, read_stream, user_status, friends_status' ) ) . '"><span class="fui-facebook"> </span><span class="colorBlue"> Login With Facebook</a></dd>';
```

When I remove the second version of this in the collapse menu. The first link works again.

So in the code below you can see the same `ifelse` is repeating to run one in the normal site and one in  `<menu class="colapsed-menu">` for mobile or smaller screens.

The second login link works but the first does not.

Could I be overriding my variable `$session` some how by setting this up like this?

```
 <body>
    <nav class="dockbar navbar-fixed-top" id="header-dockbar">
      <menu class="main-menu">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <a href="index.php" class="man-brand col-sm-3">
              <img src="img/logo.png">
            </a>
              <button id="open-close-menu" class="menu-btn btn-inverse"><span class="fui-list"></span>
            </button>
            <dl class="col-sm-8">
            <?php
            $pages = array(
                "home" => "Home", 
                "citySecrets" => "City Secrets", 
                "localBands" => "Local Bands", 
                 "places" => "Places", 
                "upcomingEvents" => "Upcoming Events"
            ); 
            $p = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : "";
            foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
            ?>
            <dd><a <?= $p == $url ? 'class="active"' : ""?> href="index.php?p=<?=$url?>" ><?=$label?> </a></dd>
            <?php
            }
  if (isset($session)){
  // print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
  echo '<dd><a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://www.foo.com/fbLogout.php' ) . '"><span class="fui-facebook"> </span><span class="colorRed"> Logout</span>' . "&nbsp" .  $graphObject['first_name'] . "&nbsp" . $graphObject['last_name'] . '</a></dd>';

} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<dd><a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'user_tagged_places, user_friends, email, publish_actions, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos, user_about_me, user_checkins, friends_checkins, user_location, friends_location, read_stream, user_status, friends_status' ) ) . '"><span class="fui-facebook"> </span><span class="colorBlue"> Login With Facebook</a></dd>';
}
            ?>
            </dl> 
          </div>
        </div>
       </menu>              
             <menu class="colapsed-menu">
        <dl>
         <?php
            $pages = array(
                "home" => "Home", 
                "citySecrets" => "City Secrets", 
                "localBands" => "Local Bands", 
                 "places" => "Places", 
                "upcomingEvents" => "Upcoming Events"
            ); 
            $p = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : "";
            foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
            ?>
            <dd><a <?= $p == $url ? 'class="active"' : ""?> href="index.php?p=<?=$url?>" > <?=$label?> </a></dd>
         <?php
            }
  if (isset($session)){
  // print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
  echo '<dd><a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://www.foo.com/fbLogout.php' ) . '"><span class="fui-facebook"> </span><span class="colorRed"> Logout</span>' . "&nbsp" .  $graphObject['first_name'] . "&nbsp" . $graphObject['last_name'] . '</a></dd>';

} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<dd><a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'user_tagged_places, user_friends, email, publish_actions, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos, user_about_me, user_checkins, friends_checkins, user_location, friends_location, read_stream, user_status, friends_status' ) ) . '"><span class="fui-facebook"> </span><span class="colorBlue"> Login With Facebook</a></dd>';
}
            ?>
        </dl>
      </menu>
    </nav>
```